# How to dynamically change partial view using Ajax and Jquery in Ruby on Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial-views, render

I have a view that has a block corresponding to a partial view (very simple).

```
<td WIDTH ="70%">
  <%= render "partial_1" %>
</td>
```

Now, When the user clicks certain button, I make a Ajax call to my controller, and after my business logic is done, I want to return to the same view but rendering a different partial view.

```
def ajax_call
    ....
    render :layout => "administracion"
end
```

I tried changing my `<%= render "partial_1" %>` for `<%= yield %>`

and in my controller: `render :layout => "administracion", :partial => "mypartial"`

but when I do this, only the partial is rendered, the other elements of my original view are lost.

What should I do?

I'm using rails 2.3.9

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the example [here](http://trevorturk.com/2010/08/24/easy-ajax-forms-with-rails-3-and-jquery/).

In a few words, you need to create a `js.erb` view and include your partial this way:

```
$('#your_container').html('<%=escape_javascript render("your_partial") %>');
```

Comment: That only puts '<%=escape_javascript render("your_partial") %>' as text in "your_container"

Comment: js.erb files are parsed by ruby interpreter, so it just works

Comment: my view should be a .js.ebr or my .js?

Comment: If you need a full re-render of page, make a standard http call instead of ajax

Comment: It's js.erb, look at my answer and at the link